# Inconsistent behavior among browsers when implementing a 'sticky footer'

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, footer, sticky

I've lost count of how many posts I've read on this subject.  Frankly I am not a CSS expert.  I cook-booked a 'sticky footer' that works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome but fails in IE9 and above.  (Its position in IE varies with the height of the browser window.  In other browsers its fixed to the bottom.)

The css is as follows:

```
#footer {
    position:relative;
    margin-top: -150px; 
    height: 150px;
    clear: both;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

The html (in the master page) is as follows:

```
 <footer>
     <div id="footer">
        <div style="margin: auto;">

        </div>
        <br />
        <div style="text-align: center; margin: auto; margin-left: auto; 
             margin-right: auto; width: 100%; margin-bottom: auto">
               <p>&copy; Copywrite blurb and date here</p>
         </div>
      </div>
 </footer>
```

Suggestions?

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/layout.css

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit of a noob too, but I feel like it is the 'position: relative' which could be messing up your code. Is your footer wrapped into another div?

Maybe try wrapping your page in a content div with a height of 100%, then position relative to this, rather than the page.

Or perhaps set the body and html to have height: 100%. What is the current height of the element surrounding your footer?

Just throwing a few ideas out there. :)

Comment: I'm going to have to put this issue off for a bit.  I'm told my current code is 'good enough' for now.  Too many other priorities.  Maybe in the next couple of months I'll get to try something more.

Answer (score 0):

For classic web sites you want to use position fixed. For a more modern, fluid, app like web application position absolute works well. You can see the latter on my demo web app, http://movies.spawebbook.com.

`#footer {
    position:absolute;
    height: 150px;
    clear: both;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}`

Comment: No offense intended Chris but I don't see anything I'd call a 'footer'  on your web page.  (Although it looks great.)

Comment: LOL, got see the source code. There is a footer element. It is used for an appBar at the bottom of the screen when the application is in a window under 600 pixels wide. The top navigation is hidden and the toolbar takes over. Inspect the markup and you can see it.